# Is Boyer More exact substring matching a paradigm of Dynamic Programming?

Tags: string, algorithm, substring, dynamic-programming, boyer-moore

I would say yes because of the use of a right table who determines how much characters you must skip. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Just because there is a table just doesn't mean it is DP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Dynamic programming is when you use past knowledge to make solving a
>   future problem easier.

which is *not* the case with Boyer-Moore string search algorithm. The key features of the algorithm are to match on the tail of the pattern rather than the head, and to skip along the text in jumps of multiple characters rather than searching every single character in the text.